# Ajax won't fire on first trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's kind a weird with my ajax. I have a function to call ajax and the structure of methods is this: When the event was triggered via enter key a certain function was called then inside that function calls an ajax function and returns a value. Actually its working well but only on second event was triggered and so on...example i focus a textbox then press enter, nothing happens at first enter, but the next time you enter it works well and so on you press enter. Anyone know why is it like that? here's my ajax code:

```
function myFunction(val){
    var passVal = updateVal(val); 
    alert(passVal); //on first load of page/after refreshing the page, this wont happen on first trigger of event
}

function updateVal(val){
    $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'updateVal.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: "val="+val,
            complete : function(data){
                bool = true;                                
            },
            error : function() {
                bool = false;
            }
    });

    return bool;
}
```

Comment: How is myFunction being called ? directly or is there any boolean check also is there any other event which will call myFunction ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax code to synchronous :

```
 $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            async: false, 
            url : 'updateVal.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: "val="+val,
            complete : function(data){
                bool = true;                                
            },
            error : function() {
                bool = false;
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax is a background call, it returns immediately; you need something like

```
function updateVal(val){
    $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'updateVal.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: "val="+val,
            success: function(data) {
                /* Do something with the DATA once the server replied, it may take a while */
                alert(data);                                
            },
            error : function() {
                alert(false);
            }
    });
}
```

This is the best way as it will not block the UI thread as a synchronous call would

Comment: I agree this probably is better - I only suggested synchronous since his code structure appeared to be based more along those lines.  Presumably, what he has shown us is just a simplified version, and it's possible his real code would be require fewer changes if it were structured as synchronous call.

Comment: Figured as much but I like to give the best solution